# io:format with multiple variables - Erlang

Tags: erlang

I am trying to use the following but with multiple parameters:

```
io:format("Message number ~s: Blah, blah", [MyNum])
```

I tried:

```
io:format("Message number ~s: ~s", [MyNum, MyMessage])
```

But is doesn't work. Is this possible with Erlang? I cannot seem to find any examples of how to do this.

Comment: In what way doesn't it work? The `~s` assumes its argument is a string.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try:

```
io:format("Message number ~p: ~p", [MyNum, MyMessage])
```

If mynum or my message are not strings/atoms, then you need to use ~p